# What does lcdc_cap error mean?

Tags: android

Just when I plug my android phone into my laptop through the USB connector, I start getting these error messages on logcat:

```
lcdc_cap    [DDMSCap]pmem_alloc size = 0x001fa420, addr = 0x401d8008
```

(keeps repeating)

I couldn't find anything about this online.

My phone is [Lenovo A820](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenovo_IdeaPhone_A820) running [Jelly Bean 4.1.2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_4.1.E2.80.934.1.2_Jelly_Bean_.28API_level_16.29)

What could be causing this?